# Image successfully builds but won't push due to auth credentials

Tags: docker, drone.io

Everything works fine with drone.io , build etc but it will not push at the very end...
Any suggestions?

```
no basic auth credentials
```

Comment: Yup. Add basic auth credentials! Well, just log in using `docker login <repository-url>` before trying to push the image.

Comment: Are you using [Docker Plugin by drone.io](http://readme.drone.io/usage/overview/)? If yes check section "Deployments" and set usename and password

Comment: recommend you post a sample .drone.yml so it is clear to viewers how you are invoking docker with drone.There is also documentation and examples for using drone with docker https://github.com/drone-plugins/drone-docker/blob/master/DOCS.md

Comment: also please update your question to specify how you are passing the docker username and password credentials to drone. This will be required, along with a sample .drone.yml, to more effectively help you debug

Answer (score 0):

Did you issued a:

```
docker login -u user -p password drone.io (or where your registry is)
```

?